# Java button display code not working

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm new to Java and I'm learning it for my computing coursework in college.
I have a button which is initially set to off(btn_state = false) while it displays the "off.png",
when the button is pressed I want the boolean var "btn_state" to set to true and display "on.png" and that if I press the button while it's set to true I want it to to set to false and display the "off.png"

If you didn't get what I said basically:

While boolean var button state = off display "off.png"
While state = on display "on.png"

When button is pressed, 
 if state = true then display "off.png" and set state = false

if state = false then display "on.png" and set state = true

I've tried making the button do as described above but failed D:, it seems pretty simple but I'm somehow incapable of coding it, maybe I'm just being stupid and going the complete wrong way about it lol, sorry if my explanation is still unclear :P

Here is the actual code:

```
JButton Gravity_btn = new JButton("");
    boolean Gravity_btn_state = false;
    while (Gravity_btn_state = false) {
        Gravity_btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("off.png"));
    }
    while (Gravity_btn_state = true) {
        Gravity_btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("on.png"));
    }

    Gravity_btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button has been pressed");
// I want it so that if "on.jpg" is showing and button is pressed then display "off.jpg" & vice versa 
    }


    });
```

Comment: You should change your button state in the listener. Also `Gravity_btn_state = false` is not the same as `Gravity_btn_state == false`.

Comment: `while (Gravity_btn_state = true)` is **setting** the variable to true, and then evaluating it. Obviously, the result will always be true. You can test `Gravity_btn_state == true`, but that's redundant, since you're just producing another boolean. The conventional (and safer) approach is to test the variable itself, e.g. `while (Gravity_btn_state)` or `while (!Gravity_btn_state)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this in completely the wrong way.

Swing uses an Event Dispatching Thread (EDT), which calls methods to handle any generated events (including user button presses).  When (and only when) those methods have returned control to the EDT will "painting" occur, which will redraw the user interface, including the any new icons on buttons.

```
while (Gravity_btn_state == false) {
    Gravity_btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("off.png"));
}
```

This loop will **never** end, locking up the user interface, and causing the application to never draw anything ever again.  Nor will it respond to any user inputs.  The button state cannot be changed, because control never returns to the EDT to accept new input from the user.  And the UI will never be drawn because control never returns to the EDT.

What you want is to install an `ActionListener` on the button.  When the button is clicked, the `ActionListener` will be invoked.  In that listener, you would toggle gravity.

Since you've talking about gravity, you probably want things moving on the screen, being pulled "down".  This means you want animation.  Which, with Swing, means you want a Swing `Timer`.  Again, the `Timer` would have an `ActionListener` which will be called when the timer expires (again, only if control always returns to the EDT).  That timer should move things (i.e., change x,y variables), and call `repaint()` on the appropriate surface ... and return control to the EDT.  The EDT will see that something needs repainting, and (if the event queue has nothing else in it) send the paint message to that thing, so it can draw itself.

There are plenty of tutorials on the Web for "Swing Animation".  Do a search on that to find the tutorials, and try to redesign your application.  If you get stuck, you can always return here for additional help.